# Inconsistent TYPE ERROR when calling method from Service in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an application displaying attachments that have been uploaded by the users.

In some situations I want to 'clean' all my Attachment-objects in MyService. Somehow I cannot call Attachment's clean method. I get the following error: *ERROR TypeError: attachment.clean is not a function*
However, when I create a new instance of Attachment I can call that method.

Since I'm new to Angular, I do not quite yet understand all the mechanics. What is going on here? And how can I fix it?

My Service class:

```
export class MyService {

    public attachments: Attachment[] = []

    populateAttachments(){
        ... //retriving data through service that populates the array
    }

    myMethod() {
        for (let attachment of this.attachments) {

            let newAttachment: Attachment = new Attachment("value1", 2, 2, "value2", "value3");
            newAttachment.clean();     // < --works just fine

            attachment.clean();        // <-- ERROR TypeError: attachment.clean is not a function
        }
    }
}
```

My Model class:

```
export class Attachment {

    type: string;
    reasonPicked: number;
    optionPicked: number;
    documentName: string;
    document: string;

    constructor(type: string, reason_picked: number, option_picked: number, documentName: string, document: string) {

        this.type = type;
        this.reasonPicked = reason_picked;
        this.optionPicked = reason_picked;
        this.documentName = documentName;
        this.document = document;

    }

    public clean() {

        this.reasonPicked = 0;
        ...

    }
}
```

Comment: I suspect you don't call the `new Attachment()` constructor on the objects of the response in your service.

Comment: That's right. The attachments are autogenerated from the rest response. Is that the reason why it is not working? I thought the generated attachments still act like normal instances of class Attachment. Apparently they don't.

Comment: Most common practice is to use interfaces for describing http response structures. The interface then only describes the response structure of your API. When you want to create class instances you would have to do this yourself. Then you also separate API structure from your application logic more clearly... but in the end this is a matter of taste. Others write application logic in services as well and reuse the given API interfaces.

Comment: You have to show us where the response is mapped into an attachement.

Comment: @ChrisY , that makes sense. I will simply manually create new instances from the generated ones when I get the API response. Thanks!